# wxPython not found error

Tags: python, wxpython

I have installed the Python version 2.7.13 and wxPython 2.8.12.1 unicode on windows 10 OS

When I try to run ride.py on the command prompt gets the following error

```
C:\Users>ride.py
wxPython not found.
You need to install wxPython 2.8.12.1 with unicode support to run RIDE.
wxPython 2.8.12.1 can be downloaded from http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/
```

[image: Software Installed Pic]

Answer (score 7):

After installing wxPython 2.8.12.1 unicode 32 bit version it resolved the issue

My python version was 64 bit, but seems RobotFramework-ride installed was 32 bit by using "pip install robotframework-ride" hence it was expecting 32 bit version of wxPython.

Comment: Saved my day after 4 hrs on re-installing and debugging :)

Comment: How and from where did you install wxPython 2.8.12.1 unicode 32 bit version?

Comment: Please find the 2.8.12.1 32 bit version from https://sourceforge.net/projects/wxpython/files/wxPython/2.8.12.1/wxPython2.8-win32-unicode-2.8.12.1-py27.exe/download